# Статический ключ во ViewModel

Tags: android, kotlin, livedata

Есть проект, написанный другим программистом. И вот в нем есть вот такой код

```
class CardsViewModel : ViewModel() {
    val selected = MutableLiveData<PaymentCard>()

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        var keyId = 0
    }
}
```

Каждый раз когда во ViewModel кладут какие-то данные этот keyId инкрементится:

```
val cardsViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(requireActivity())
                    .get(CardsViewModel.keyId.toString(), CardsViewModel::class.java)
                CardsViewModel.keyId++
                cardsViewModel.selected.value = PaymentCard.EMPTY
```

Потом получает его таким способом

```
val cardsViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(requireActivity()).get(CardViewModel.keyId.toString(), CardsViewModel::class.java)
 bindingId = cardsViewModel.selected.value?.bindingId ?: ""
```

Я только недавно начал изучать LiveData и мне непонятно что этот id дает и как с ним работать? 
У меня сложилось впечатление, что я кладу данные, привязанные к какому-то ключу и потом извлекаю их по этому ключу=) Но это вызывает много вопросов.

P.S. Проект писали плохо, поэтому возможно это какой-то костыль, но в силу отсутствия опыта работы с LiveData я не могу понять этого.

Comment: Больше похоже на то,  что тот кто писал это просто отслеживал,  сколько раз ViewModel  создается при работе приложения,  просто для себя

Comment: К LiveData как таковому этот ключ не имеет никакого отношения.